# When I delete the object that I have detailed with Navigation Link, I crash on return

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift-data

This is where i get the details.

```
struct BooksListView: View {
    @Query var books: [Book]

    @State private var searchedBook: String = ""
    
    var newBooks: [Book] {
        if searchedBook.isEmpty {
            return books
        } else {
            return books.filter {$0.name.contains(searchedBook)}
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color("customBackground").ignoresSafeArea()
            ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
                ForEach(newBooks) { book in
                    NavigationLink {
                        BookCardDetailsView(book: book)
                    } label: {
                        BookCardView(book: book)
                    }

                }
            }
            .searchable(text: $searchedBook, placement: .navigationBarDrawer(displayMode: .always))
            .navigationTitle("Books")
        }
    }
}
```

And in details I delete book with this

```
                        Menu {
                            Button {
                                modelContext.delete(book)
                                presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                            } label: {
                                Label("Delete", systemImage: "trash")
                            }

                        } label: {
                            Image(systemName: "ellipsis")
                                .foregroundStyle(Color(.blue))
                                .padding(6)

                        }
```

When its get back to list view I get crash.

Could not cast value of type 'Swift.Optional' (0x1e748b1f8) to 'Swift.String' (0x1e7483e68).

```
{
    @storageRestrictions(accesses: _$backingData, initializes: _name)
        init(initialValue) {
                    _$backingData.setValue(forKey: \.name, to: initialValue)
                    _name = _SwiftDataNoType()
        }

    get {
                    _$observationRegistrar.access(self, keyPath: \.name)
                    return self.getValue(forKey: \.name)
        }

    set {
                    _$observationRegistrar.withMutation(of: self, keyPath: \.name) {
                            self.setValue(forKey: \.name, to: newValue)
                    }
        }
}
```

this code block appears in my Book model.

```
@Model
final class Book: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID().uuidString
    var name: String
    var category: Category?
    var author: Author?
    var printDate: String
    var printLenght: Int
    var language: String
    var currentPage: Int = 0
    var isbn: String?
    
    @Attribute(.externalStorage)
    var imageData: Data?
    
    var isFavorite: Bool = false
    var isBookmark: Bool = false
    
    @Relationship(deleteRule: .nullify, inverse: \Category.books)
    @Relationship(deleteRule: .nullify, inverse: \Author.books)
    
    init(name: String, printDate: String, printLenght: Int, language: String, imageData: Data?) {
        self.name = name
        self.printDate = printDate
        self.printLenght = printLenght
        self.language = language
        self.imageData = imageData
    }
}
```

The crash only happens on device. Not on simulators. Sometimes works on device and not works on simulators. I can't understand the problem.

Comment: The crash happens after i get back to the list view not on delete part. And i can delete the book in list view. I think when i delete the book in details and get back to the list view it can't find the book i deleted and get crashed.

Comment: Call modelContext.save() directly after the delete and see if it helps.

Comment: yes its help thank you. As i know, delete method has save function too why in this case we need to save again ? @JoakimDanielson

Comment: "delete method has save function too", no it doesn't but maybe you mean automatic saving for the model context? Anyway I believe the error is caused by the fact that the automatic save is performed in the background with a small delay and that you return to the previous view directly after the delete so there is some kind of synchronisation issue. If this is the case it could also explain why you get different results in the simulator and a real device.

Comment: i see thank you for your response. Yes i thought delete method has save func because of that automatic saving. Thank you again. @JoakimDanielson